# local storage/ checkbox/ does not display the values

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to print a checkbox values to another HTML page using local storage, but it did not display to another HTML page

**Here my page1 HTML**

```html
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="option1" name="car1" value="BMW">
            <label for="vehicle1">BMW</label><br>
            <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="option2" name="car2" value="Ferrari">
            <label for="vehicle2">Ferrari</label><br>
            <input checkbox="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="option3" name="car3" value="Ford">
            <label for="vehicle3">Ford</label><br>
            <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="option4" name="car4" value="Audi">
            <label for="vehicle4">Audi</label><br>
            <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="option5" name="car5" value="Cadillac">
            <label for="vehicle5">Cadillac</label><br>
```

**Here my javascript code**

```js
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox" && inputs[i].checked) {
            count2++;
            localStorage.setItem("checkvalue", inputs[i].value);

        }
    }
```

```html
<script>
// page2 HTML
            <span id="result"></span>,Welcome
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("checkvalue");
        </script>
```

Comment: You are overwriting the `checkvalue` value in each iteration. Also for more consistency, you need to make a JSON and then store the JSON in the localStorage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @SMAKSS mentioned, you are overriding your localstorage on each iteration.

Instead of

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox" && inputs[i].checked) {
    count2++;
    localStorage.setItem("checkvalue", inputs[i].value);
  }
}
```

You should

```
localStorage.setItem("results", JSON.stringify(inputs));
```

And retrieve it by

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("results"));
```